# Python Entry Button Submit issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Currently with the below code I seem to be getting a weird issue as well cant seem to get the value of refreshtoken when I click the submit button. I do get the print for word but for refreshtoken I receive .!entry in the Console.

```
def getCommand(r):
print('word')
print(r)


tokenWindowFrame = Tk()
tokenWindowFrame.title("Add Character")
refreshLabel = ttk.Label(tokenWindowFrame, text="Refresh Token : ")
refreshLabel.grid(row=1,column=1)
refreshToken = ttk.Entry(tokenWindowFrame, width = 50)
refreshToken.grid(row=1,column=2)
button = ttk.Button(tokenWindowFrame, text = "Submit", command=lambda 
r=refreshToken: getCommand(r))
button.grid(row=3,column=2)



tokenWindowFrame.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need `print(r.get())`.

Comment: please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: @BryanOakley their is nothing wrong with the Indentation of the code I posted and is completely valid in Python

Comment: That is not true. `def getCommand(r):` is at exactly the same level of indentation of `print('word')`. Remember, we can't see your fine, we can only see what you post in the question.

Comment: If you look closley which I can tell you are not the line above is the same line so in reality you are looking at Notice how there is a ) at the end. ttk.Button(tokenWindowFrame, text = "Submit", command=lambda r=refreshToken: getCommand(r))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change this line 
   `button = ttk.Button(tokenWindowFrame, text = "Submit", command=lambda r=refreshToken: getCommand(r))`
To : 
`button = ttk.Button(tokenWindowFrame, text = "Submit", command=lambda r=refreshToken: getCommand(r.get()))`

The r.get() is what I was missing. As both print(r.get()) would not work in the Function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't print an entry object, you need to print the text in the entry object. Use:

```
refreshToken.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text in an entry box you need:

```
<entry_box>.get()
```

If you are trying to print it then you could just do:

```
print(<entry_box>.get())
```

Or in your case:
    `print(r.get())`

Hope this works for you!